# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnyObject - Approach

Tags: ios, swift, let

The following code throws a message which says "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnyObject'"

```
    func parseData2(){
        var data:NSData?


        if let data2 = data  {
            do {
                let details = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: .AllowFragments)

                if let actualDetails = details where actualDetails.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary) {
                    print("Parse Data")
                }

            }catch {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

To resolve the above error I used the following code.

```
    func parseData2(){
        var data:NSData?


        if let data2 = data  {
            do {
                let details:AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: .AllowFragments)

                if let actualDetails:AnyObject = details where actualDetails.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary) {
                    print("Parse Data")
                }

            }catch {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

Is there any better approach then the above or my code might crash?

There is one more code which I want to add considering **nil check**,**type check** and then **type cast check**. The reason behind that Swift offers great flexibility but litle bit difficult to fix issues. Let's say I have a dictionary, **cityDetails** and I am trying to get data for  self.cityZipCode and self.cityIdentifier, which are optional, defined as var cityZipCode:Int? and  var cityIdentifier:Int?

```
if let cityBasic = cityDetails["basicDetails"] where 
cityBasic!.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary) {

self.cityZipCode = (cityBasic as! NSDictionary)["zip"].integerValue ?? 0

self.cityIdentifier =  (cityBasic as! NSDictionary)["cityId"].integerValue ?? 0

}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking in the update of your question? Either clarify how it relates to the first part or ask a new question for the new part. At the moment your title refers to an `Optional Binding` issue, your first part is about `do try catch` and now it is about `down casting` and `nil coalescing operator`

Comment: I am bit confused with nil check , type check and then downcasting, how all these things work together? Simple code but lots of understanding is required for it.

Comment: [is and as](http://www.codingexplorer.com/type-casting-swift/), [optional binding](http://www.codingexplorer.com/multiple-optional-bindings-swift-1-2/), [do try catch](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch). Google is your friend for general language questions. Especially when it concerns the most written about stuff

Comment: nil check is a simple if else depending on nil/value. Optional Binding gives you a non optional result from an optional input. Type check is a simple if else depending on type. down casting gives you an optional result of a specific type.

Comment: have you had a chance to look at those links?

Comment: multiple optional binding is the best explained here, something I would not find easily with books.

Comment: I added some extra code illustrating multiple optional bindings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to unwrap the result from `try`. It is not an optional. You do need to cast the result from `try` to an `NSDictionary`. Use `as?` to downcast it.

**Best practice**: full access to returned error for good error handling

```
func parseData2(){
    var data:NSData?

    if let data2 = data  {
        do {
            let details = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: .AllowFragments)

            if let detailsDict = details as? NSDictionary {
                print("Parse Data")
            } else if let detailsArray = details as? NSArray {
                print("array")
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Quick and dirty**: error handling is not for me!

```
func parseData2(){
    var data:NSData?

    if let data2 = data  {

        let details = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: .AllowFragments)

        if let detailsDict = details as? NSDictionary {
            print("Parse Data")
        } else {
            print("details might be nil, or not an NSDictionary")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Bad Ass Mode**: crashes are features

```
func parseData2(){
    var data:NSData?

    if let data2 = data  {

        let details = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

    }
}
```

---

Some extra info on multiple unwraps :
Drop the code below in a playground.

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var anOptional : Int?
    init() {
    }
}

func unwrapWithIfLet() {

    if let unWrappedStruct = myStruct, let unWrappedSomething = unWrappedStruct.anOptional {
        print("multiple optional bindings succeeded")
        // both unWrappedStruct and unWrappedSomething are available here
    } else {
        print("something is nil")
    }
}

func unwrapWithGuard() {

    guard let unWrappedStruct = myStruct, let unWrappedSomething = unWrappedStruct.anOptional else {
        print("something is nil")
        return
    }
    print("multiple optional bindings succeeded")
    // both unWrappedStruct and unWrappedSomething are available here
}


var myStruct : SomeStruct?

//unwrapWithGuard()
//unwrapWithIfLet()

myStruct = SomeStruct()
myStruct!.anOptional = 1

unwrapWithGuard()
unwrapWithIfLet()
```

Comment: Ok, In case if I don't want to use try catch and check two things, object is not nil and isKindOfClass NSArray. How can done in the simplest way.

Comment: "crashes are features" up you go

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `as?`, which attempts to convert the thing on the left to the type on the right, and returns nil if the conversion is not possible:

```
let details = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: .AllowFragments)

if let actualDetails = details as? NSDictionary {
    print("Parse Data")
}
```

You rarely need to use `isKindOfClass` in Swift. If you find yourself using it, ask why, and consider whether `as` or `as?` will work instead.

Comment: What if details is not null and happens to be a NSArray?

Comment: Your original code was explicitly checking for NSDictionary, so I assumed that you specifically needed a dictionary for your parsing to work. If you can work with a dictionary _or_ an array, then you don’t need the type check at all; just remove `.AllowFragments`, and it will only allow dictionaries and arrays. Please describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: [Reply to deleted comment from R Menke]: From the original code, it looked like the asker was trying to work with a dictionary, in which case they need a variable of type `NSDictionary`, in which case `as?` in a conditional unwrapping is the correct approach. If their parser code should proceed _only_ if the result is an `NSDictionary` but does not actually need any dictionary-specific calls (which is unlikely but possible), then `is` would indeed be appropriate.

Comment: @PaulCantrell yeah I was working on this in a playground with the limited code available and I was too fast. I was only responding to his comment on my answer where he said he needed to check a type. Wasn't anticipating the needed downcast.  `is` only works as check, not to cast it to a type.